# Integrating standalone GeoWebcache with client?

Tags: geowebcache

I have installed GeoServer on machine 1 (windows) and GeoWebCache on machine 2 (windows). What I need to achieve is tile caching so that the client can be served maps from cache there by enhancing the performance of the client.

I am still not sure if My client should connect to GeoWebcache or Geoserver for fetching maps? In either of the case, what configurations are required and at what place to have my client leverage the cache feature.

Requesting some assistance/guidance on the above queries which is purely from integration side of it.

Comment: 1: Clients connect with GeoWebcache http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/introduction/whatis.html 2: By using some of the supported service types http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/index.html 3: This is not relevant due to point 1.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Thank you user30184. I am able to see the layers on GeoWebCache that are coming from GeoServer. In the GeoWebCache home page, I have now selected the GetCapabilities link (for WMS) and it displays a long text on browser (which is an XML file when I view the source). This string/XML has all the layers in it and I can see a URL like "localhost:8080/geowebcache/service/…;. I have tried to use this URL on client to use cache tiles from GeoWebCache directly but nothing happens. Please suggest if there is anything I am missing out here as I am new to GeoServer arena

Comment: What client? What do you mean "nothing happens"? You need to edit your question to specify what you are trying to achieve, what you've tried, what worked, what didn't work, and what happened instead.